# Magento 2 Change price for configurable product using plugin

Tags: magento2, module, price, plugin

I need to change price of products using plugin. I used following method for it.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_price" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Created following plugin class:

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin;

    class Price
    {
        public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result){


            return $result;
        }
    }
```

This is working perfectly for simple product but this is not working with configurable product. I need to carry all type of products.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this offline? as I am in the same situation

Comment: Thank you, Nope, I did't get answer but I checked that product is having parent configurable product or not. If yes then I wrote code to change the price of that particular product.